# What's the opposite of reckless?

Tags: antonyms

What is an adjective to describe someone who is the opposite of reckless other than 'cautious' or 'careful'?

Comment: There are too many possibilities. Please be specific, provide context or draw an analogy.

Comment: "pusillanimous" (lacking courage or resolution; cowardly; faint-hearted).

Comment: I'm not sure that it's officially recognized as a word, but "reckful" gets lots of google hits including https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reckful.  "Full of careful heed or attention; careful; cautious."

Comment: I rather like _reckful_.

Answer (score 5):

The classical meaning of reckless is- not giving enough thought to your actions or decisions. It this case the opposite or adjective to describe someone who is the opposite of reckless would be **prudent** as in

> "no **prudent** money manager would authorize a loan without first knowing its purpose"

There could very well be many more possible answers but they all depend on the context of usage of reckless.

Comment: Hope it helps, although more elaboration in your question is need, as to what is the context of usage of reckless, how is it/the person described to be reckless, so on and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

I like the word **measured**, but it would apply more to a person's actions than their character. Context is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Akash Vartak gives a great general-purpose antonym for *reckless*, but there are better in some specific contexts.  For example, in American English, in the context of driving a motor vehicle, ***safe*** is the most conventional antonym.  According to Merriam-Webster:

> 2a: secure from threat of danger, harm, or loss
>
> 3: affording safety or security from danger, risk, or difficulty
>
> 6a: not likely to take risks :  cautious

One might also use *cautious* or *careful* to describe driving style, but probably not *prudent*.